# Unable to restore the bak file in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have taken a backup from SQL Server 2008 version 10.50.2500

I tried restoring in another system having same but version 10.00.1600

So how to upgrade to that version or what is the solution for this ?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

- `v10.50` is SQL Server **2008 R2** (and the R2 is important) - that's not just a service pack on top of the 2008 version - it's a totally separate, distinct SQL Server version
- you **cannot** restore that version back to an earlier SQL Server **2008** (`v10.0`) instance; there's no way, no tool, no hack, no workaround to achieve this

SQL Server backups are **never** backwards compatible, their internal structures just change too much from version to version.

If you backup a database from SQL Server **2008 R2**, you must restore to **2008 R2** (or newer, like SQL Server 2012).

Answer (score 1):

As others have said there is no way to move a database backup to an earlier version, however whatever you're trying to do with a backup restore, you can solve with the database copy wizard:

Here's a link to get you started:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx

It's pretty intuitive, and you can find tons of documentation elsewhere.

The only thing I'll advise is if you want to set up a process rather than do it once, to check the create SSIS package checkbox at the end, again lots of guides around the details.